# OpenSSL error (self signed certificate in certificate chain)

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, self-signed-certificate

I am trying to set up a ruby project on MacOS for my work. But i faced a problem with openssl. The error is attached with photo.
[image]
My colleague has faced the same issue and by his words he had fixed it with adding the following two statement to `.zshrc`

```
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

But it doesn't work for me. In this case i get an error

```
SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=error: certificate verify failed (Host mismatch)
```

Now i have the following `.zshrc`

```
export SSL_CERT_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/certs
export SSL_CERT_FILE=/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/cert.pem
export PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/openssl@3/bin:$PATH"export
```

I use

```
rvm 1.29.12
ruby 3.0.3p157
OpenSSL 3.1.0 14 Mar 2023
```

Comment: "host mismatch" means that the subject/SAN of the certificate does not match the name you used to access it in the URL. No further details can be given since neither certificate nor URL used are known.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich But i was able to fix it, now the problem is self-signed certificate.

Comment: You did not fix it, you just hid the error by getting a new error. It checks first if it can validate the certificate chain - which it could before but cannot do any more after your change to SSL_CERT_DIR etc. That's why it fails with "self signed certificate in chain" and does not even bother to check for matching hostname as it did before. So - go back to what your friend suggested and then make sure that the hostname matches.